# Magento 2 Advanced Reporting User Role permissions

Tags: magento2, user-roles, advanced-reporting

I have enabled Advanced Reporting (Magento 2's free one) in the back end, and from my main admin back end account, it is working fine, the subscription is set up and figures are updated daily.
I have set up a new user account on the back end for office managers who don't need all the confifguration settings, and created a new user role group for them and set up permissions including advanced reporting as per screen shot:
[image: Screenshot permissions]

While logged into the new manager account set to this new role, I cannot access the advanced reporting. I need them to have permission to access it. When logged in and clicking on advanced reporting, I get the error message: "Sorry, you need permissions to view this content."
Are there hidden or special permissions for the advanced reporting feature, or will it simply not work without the backend user having full access rights to everything?

Answer (score 1):

Permission also needs to be granted to:
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone get a resolution to this?

I have a client that requires access, but don't wish to give them full admin access. I have selected what I believe are the correct option in the user roles, but maybe there is one I'm missing?